# Программа на C не работает с русскими символами

Tags: c

Следующая программа при вводе символа определяет согласный он или нет, но она не работает если в ней будут стоять руские символы и выводит ошибку:

```
   **error** character too large for enclosing character literal type
```

с англоизычной раскладкой все в порядке и программа запускается, что делать чтобы заработала с русскими буквами?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

char c;
int isTrueC;

printf("Введите букву\n");
scanf("%c", &c);

isTrueC = (c == 'а' || c == 'е' || c == 'и' || c == 'о' || с == 'ы' || c == 'э' || c == 'ю' || c == 'я');

if (isTrueC) 
printf("вы ввели гласны символ %c\n", c);
else 
printf("символ %c согласный /n", c);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Единственное переносимое решение в рамках С — использовать широкие символы. Для системы с однобайтовой локалью есть варианты: хранить исходники в этой локали или компилировать так, чтобы строки перекодировались в неё при компиляции (`-fexec-charset` для gcc). Если малость конкретизируешь вопрос, то распишу подробней...

Comment: Друг мне очень интересно фраза - "использовать широкие символы" что ты имеешь ввиду?Насчет конкретики вопроса я же написал как мне сделать чтобы заработало с русскими символами и если есть способ сделать это и объяснить буду благодарен в долгу не останусь

Comment: @Евгений Щелоков, "широкие символы" - довольно распространённое понятие. Это тип wchar_t, и связанные с ним функции. Здесь можно их посмотреть, есть все аналоги тех же функций, но работающих с обычными символами: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/wchar.h

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <locale.h>
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
```

Надо добавить эти строки, добавив русскую локаль, тогда должно заработать.

Comment: куда вставить вторую строку

Comment: сразу в main() вставьте

Comment: не помагает, пробывал уже  @Man1nHat